# bufferedReader reads the filename only

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I am building an android app where one of the functionality is that i write on a .txt file and late try to read it. Its very simple. But when I try to read the file using a BufferedReader it only gives me the name of the file and not the content withing.Below is my code(just the concerned portion)

```
File curFile = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/Notes/"+fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(curFile));
StringBuilder note = new StringBuilder(500);
String content;

while((content = br.readLine())!= null) {
    ShowToast("Inside While: "+ content);//prints only fileName
    note.append(content);
    note.append('\n');
}
```

what is it that i am doing wrong?!

Comment: What are the contents of the file?  How did you create it?

Comment: Try: new FileReader(String filePath);

Comment: How often does it print the filename? Well very sure the file only contains the filename. And that is because you wrote it in. But as you did not post how you created the file its merely a guess.

Comment: no i have some text in the file and its not just filename. I had created text file from this app only

Comment: Edit the code which creates the file into your app.  Consider temporarily moving the file to the external storage, or using the emulator, so that you can adb pull the file and examine it.

Comment: This code reads the contents of the file. Ergo if it prints the filename, the contents of the file must be the filename.

Comment: yes, you all are ryt..i read my code again(may be 10th time) and i found out that i have been writing the filename only into the file.MY BAD! thanx for ur help though guys